# IBM Worklight 6.2 ChallengeHandler submitFailure: doesn't behave as expected

Tags: ios, objective-c, ibm-mobilefirst

I am using Worklight 6.2 iOS native framework. I have implemented a custom `MyChallengeHandler` that subclasses `ChallengeHandler`, and logging in:

```
[[WLClient sharedInstance] login:@"SomeRealm" withDelegate:LoginListener];
```

In `ChallengeHandler` I can submit success, which calls `onSuccess:` in `LoginListener`:

```
[self submitSuccess:response];
```

However, I can't submit failure, which I was expecting to call `onFailure:` in `LoginListener`. In fact, it looks like there is no effect when calling `submitFailure:` and `onFailure:` never gets called in `LoginListener`.

Also, I don't see a declaration of `submitFailure:` in WL `ChallengeHandler` header, it is available only in `BaseChallengeHandler`.

My main point is, currently it looks like the `LoginListener` `onFailure:` method is never called, but there are cases when the `handleChallenge:` should fail. And LoginListener should get released.

Is this a known issue in Worklight, is there any workaround?

Update 1:

Just found a similar problem for JS client API, which isn't useful for native:
[Adapter procedure call, reporting an authentication failure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16717325/adapter-procedure-call-reporting-an-authentication-failure)

Update 2:

This might be important. I am using Adapter authentication, but in the IBM example there is `submitLoginForm:`, maybe my issue is for Adapter authentication only.

```
[self submitAdapterAuthentication:invocationData options:nil]
```

Comment: First thing I notice, you wrote `ChallangeHandler` instead of `ChallengeHandler` (e not a). Not sure if it's just here or in your real code too...

Comment: (same for `handleChallange` instead of `handleChallenge`)

Comment: It was typo in the post, it is ChallengeHandler obviously.

Answer (score 0):

It's a big vague so far but I will write some possibilities I think of. Let me know if any help, and I will update my answer.

1) Your code above says you use the class `ChallangeHandler`. I am not sure if the typo is only in StackOverflow or in your real code as well, but the class is `ChallengeHandler`, with a `e`.

Same for `handleChallange` instead of `handleChallenge`.

2) Did you register your challenge handler somewhere?

`[[WLClient sharedInstance] registerChallengeHandler:[[MyChallengeHandler alloc] initWithViewController:self] ];`

3) Do you ever get to the success of your LoginListener? And of your challenge handler?

You are correct that the documentation does not mentiond submitFailure - I will look into that.

However in code I wrote, I was able to use this without problems.

```
@implementation MyChallengeHandler
//...
-(void) onSuccess:(WLResponse *)response {
    NSLog(@"inside challenge success");
    [self.vc.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    [self submitSuccess:response];
}

-(void) onFailure:(WLFailResponse *)response {
    NSLog(@"inside challenge failure");
    [self submitFailure:response];
}
```

Comment: 1) Typo in the post
2) Yes, I have registered the ChallengeHandler.
3) Yes, onSuccess: works fine. I can submitSuccess: without any problems in handleChallenge:. The problem is only for submitFailure:, if I want to give up in handleChallenge: for some reason.